# Why doesn't this write data into the created file? Python

Tags: python, file-io, python-3.x

## Why does this create the file but not write the code into it?

```
import os

#List for text
mainlist = []

#Definitions
def main():
  print("Please Input Data(Type 'Done' When Complete):")
  x = input()
  if x.lower() == 'done':
   sort(mainlist)
  else:
    mainlist.append(x)
    main()

def sort(mainlist):
  mainlist = sorted(mainlist, key=str.lower)
  for s in mainlist:
    finalstring = '\n'.join(str(mainlist) for mainlist in mainlist)
  print(finalstring)

  print("What would you like to name the file?:") 
  filename = input()

  with open(filename + ".txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(str(finalstring))

    print("\nPress Enter To Terminate.")
    c = input()  

main()

#Clears to prevent spam.
os.system("cls")
```

The file is made, and the data is stored... But finalstring's content isn't written into it. The file remains blank.

Comment: I ran your code and it looks ok, didn't get the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling `sort(mainlist)` multiple times and the file is being overwritten each time. Change the open mode to `a` like:

```
with open(filename + ".txt", "a") as f:
    f.write(str(finalstring))
```

See http://docs.python.org/3.2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

Comment: Thanks! I actually found where the bug was... It worked, but it only happened after the terminal was terminated. Thanks for what you said as it lead to me finding the 'issue'. Thanks :D.